# SelectedItem binding is not updating the ViewModel

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I feel like I'm missing something obvious because this is so simple. Thanks in advance for the help. I'm struggling with binding the SelectedItem of a simple ListView in a Xamarin application. I'm testing on UWP and am using Prism's MVVM BindableBase base class.  Here's what I'm experiencing:

1. The page loads and nothing in the list is selected.
2. I select an item in the list.
3. The setter of `SelectedGrade` is called with a `value` of `null`.
4. After that, selecting items does not cause the `SelectedGrade` setter to be called.

Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="#7F7F7F"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Grades, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGrade, Mode=TwoWay}"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
          RowHeight="50">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="10">
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           TextColor="#272832"/>
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Text="{Binding Score}"
                           TextColor="Aquamarine" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>                
</ListView>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
Grade _selectedGrade;
public Grade SelectedGrade
{
    get { return _selectedGrade; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedGrade, value); } // this gets set to NULL the first time i select an item then never gets set again
}
```

**Edit:** I've also added an `ItemSelected` event listener in the code-behind and it is not being fired after the initial item is selected. The one time it is fired, the `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` reveal that the ListView's `SelectedItem` is null. I can also see at this time that the ListView's ItemsSource has a collection of three items in it, as I would expect. I'm quite confused as to why the ListView thinks the `SelectedItem` is null and why it is not broadcasting when the selected item changes.

Comment: Have you debugged it putting a breakpoint in the SelectedGrade `get` ? You should watch if the view "request" it

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez, the getter only gets called once when the page loads and the SelectedGrade is null. Then the setter is called (with a null value for some reason) when an item is first selected. Then neither the getter or setter are called again, despite other items in the ListView being selected.

Comment: I've also added an `ItemSelected` event handler to the code-behind and it is not firing after initial item selection. It seems the ListView is not broadcasting when the selected item changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a bug in Xamarin. I upgraded from Xamarin.Forms `3.0.0.550146` to `3.1.0.637273` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the similar  issue when List does not bind to view model with `SelectedItem` and Xamarin forms 5.0.0.2244.
It was resolved with setting default value of List property to new List() object  instead null value in the view model before setting binding context . After that binding has became working.